# Create a session before an ajax call

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

I have this website where I can interact with the web both as a logged or anonymus user. When I click a link I call an ajax function:

you click here:

```
<a id="alcrearuta" class="'.$row->urlamigable.'" href="#">añadir a ruta</a>
```

This is my ajax function:

```
var valor=$("#alcrearuta").attr('class');
$("#alcrearuta").click(function(){
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "../ajax/ruta.php",
        data: "urlamigable=" + valor,
        dataType: 'html',
        success: function(data) {
            $("#listaruta").html(data);
        }
    });        
});
```

The thing is I have two possibilities: either a logged user clicks the link and the ruta.php does its stuff on the database considering the userid that's set in the session or I have an anonymous user that wants to do something similar.

In my ruta.php I have:

```
if(!empty($_SESSION['Username'])){
    //Insert stuff on DB
}else{
    //I wish I could create the session here but I can't since it's an ajax call
}
```

What I need is at some point between the click in the link and the end of the ajax function I can set my $SESSION['Username'] variable to get a new value (since the user it's not logged in, it's currently empty and thus my inserts on the database not working)

Comment: why would ajax interfere with initializing your session... a request is a request s far as the server is concerened.

Comment: has he logged in and seeing this stuff or this is the login page?

Comment: in your screen do you not have a username displayed once logged in? if so, your javascript could check it, or, change the ajax calls via PHP eg, write out different ajax javascript depending on if the user is logged in or not, via a session

Comment: To utilise sessions you must append session_start(); at the top of each page, if you place this on your ajax page at the top, and again in your ruta.php page you can utilise the session variables.  When you send a GET to the ruta.php page you can set the session var under the conditions you specifify. Just on your index page it will not appear to be set as your page has been pre-processed, is this what you mean?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if you want to use sessions in php, your php script (ruta.php) schould start with

```
session_start();
```

from that point you can assign any variable to $_SESSION['Username']

```
$_SESSION['Username'] = something_to_generate_a_Username;
```

Just like any other server request.

Comment: Omg I can't believe I forgot this. I assumed it was in the first include that I did on the ruta.php file but it wasn't. Thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

You could use jquery cookie library to create a session cookie.

```
$.cookie("Username", "NOTLOGGEDINUSER");

https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie

http://www.electrictoolbox.com/jquery-cookies/

and in beforeSend for Ajax, you can check if username cookie exists, other wise, create the cookie with "NOTLOGGEDINUSER"
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe on the click do another AJAX call just to set the SESSION?